# Tengo dos selectonemenu en Primefaces. ¿Como hago para obligar a que se seleccione alguno de los dos o ambos?

Tags: java, primefaces, xhtml

una consulta por favor, tengo dos selectOneMenu de primefaces en una vista, lo que necesito hacer es que el usuario si no selecciono ninguno de los dos seleccione mínimo uno.

Puse required=true pero esto me hace tener que seleccionar ambos selectOneMenu y la idea es que si el usuario quiere solo puede seleccionar uno. Tendría que haber un if o algo así para condicionarlos pero no sé como hacerlo

Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1):

Una solución sería añadir una validación en el submit del formulario, ejemplo un botón type= submit.

ejemplo de boton primefaces:

```
   <p:commandButton id="buscarPreciosSinFiltro2"  value="enviar" actionListener = "#{nombreBean.metodoValidar}" update = "id del los elementos que quieres refrescar"/>
```

En el método del bean recuperas los atributos value del selectOneMenu o lo que sea y si no hay al menos una informado muestra un mensaje en la misma página en vez de seguir navegando.

para mostrar el mensaje tal que asi desde el BB:

```
 FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN, "Warning!", "Selecciona una al menos bribón."));
```

Answer (score 0):

He implementado algo así pero entre dos autocomplete. La idea principal es que cuando selecciona uno, el otro lo hace `null` y esa condición es la que pongo en el `required` de cada uno.
En mi caso tengo `persona` y `proveedor` y se debe seleccionar o uno o el otro. Cada autocomplete tiene lo siguiente, persona y proveedor respectivamente:

```
// Persona
required="#{usuariosControl.usuarioSeleccionado.idProveedor eq null}"

// Proveedor
required="#{usuariosControl.usuarioSeleccionado.idPersona eq null}"
```

Tengo dos eventos ajax que se llaman cuando se selecciona cada uno que vuelven `null` al otro. Además de un `update` para el otro.
De esa manera lo he resuelto yo.

Saludos.